# "Axis limits cannot be NaN or Inf" when setting the left xlim to 1

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was working with the secondary axis tutorial of matplotlib:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(1, 360, 5), range(1, 360, 5))
ax.set_xlabel('frequency [Hz]')

def invert(x):
    # 1/x with special treatment of x == 0
    x = np.array(x).astype(float)
    near_zero = np.isclose(x, 0)
    x[near_zero] = np.inf
    x[~near_zero] = 1 / x[~near_zero]
    return x

ax.set_xlim(left=1,right=360)
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0,360,10))
secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(invert, invert))
secax.set_xticks(1/np.linspace(1,360,5))
secax.set_xlabel('Period [s]')
#secax.set_xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

When I set slim left=1, the following error appears:

```
ValueError: Axis limits cannot be NaN or Inf
```

I have tested that by changing the x_lim to:

```
ax.set_xlim(right=360)
```

The right figure is created:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure why but you fix this error by putting `ax.set_xlim(left=1,right=360)` to the end directly before `plt.show()`.

Apparently this makes it smoother to compute all the properties of the top axis. Alternatively it works to choose negative values for the left limit of the bottom x-axis, e.g. -1. The default values for these limits are `ax.get_xlim()` --> (-16.75, 373.75).

Best,
Sarah